# golang unix.TCGETS equivalent on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, go

On Linux I use the following code to enable and disable console echo:

```
unix.IoctlGetTermios(int(os.Stdin.Fd()), unix.TCGETS)
unix.IoctlSetTermios(unix.Stdout, unix.TCSETS, term)
```

But it won't compile on Mac, what should I use on Mac?

Comment: How exactly it wouldn't compile? Can you share a specific error?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TIOCGETA` and `TIOCSETA` instead on Mac OS

```
// IoctlSetTermios performs an ioctl on fd with a *Termios.
//
// The req value will usually be TCSETA or TIOCSETA.
func IoctlSetTermios(fd int, req uint, value *Termios) error {
```

```golang
import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"

        "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
        STDIN := int(os.Stdin.Fd())

        tio, err := unix.IoctlGetTermios(STDIN, unix.TIOCGETA)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Input sth:")

        tio.Lflag &^= unix.ECHO
        err = unix.IoctlSetTermios(STDIN, unix.TIOCSETA, tio)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        line, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        tio.Lflag |= unix.ECHO
        err = unix.IoctlSetTermios(STDIN, unix.TIOCSETA, tio)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(line)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `unix.TCGETS` / `unix.TIOCGETA` or `unix.TCSETS` / `unix.TIOCSETA` you can define constants in different files and then use build constraints to build those files based on the operating system.

You can check how `github.com/moby/term` does it here:

https://github.com/moby/term/blob/c43b287e0e0f2460e4ba913936af2f6bdcbe9ed5/termios_bsd.go
https://github.com/moby/term/blob/c43b287e0e0f2460e4ba913936af2f6bdcbe9ed5/termios_nonbsd.go

With this method your code is decoupled from the operating system and you can always use the same constant.